# Añadir un destructor virtual a una clase virtual provoca un fallo en tiempo de ejecución (GCC vs CLang)

Tags: c++, herencia

El problema que he encontrado es fácilmente reproducible con estos dos objetos relacionados mediante herencia:

```
struct B
{
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

struct D : B
{
    void update() override
    {
        std::cout << this << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
```

Dispongo de unos alias que definen un *wrapper* sobre `B` que es guardado en un `std::stack`:

```
using Base = std::reference_wrapper<B>;
using Bases = std::stack<Base>;

Bases bases;
```

Y dos funciones que dan uso a dichos alias:

```
void push(B &&b)
{
    bases.push_back(b);
}

void update()
{
    bases.top().get().update();
}
```

Cuando [lo ejecuto, tanto con GCC como con CLang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vKYh1ZntsiQAEPZK) parece funcionar:

```
int main()
{
    push(D{});
    update();

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> 0x7ffd064ecd68 virtual void D::update()
> ```

Pero si añado un destructor a `B`:

```
struct B
{
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual ~B() = default; // <--- ¡Nueva línea!
};
```

GCC falla:

> ```
> pure virtual method called
> terminate called without an active exception
>
> Aborted
> ```

Pero CLang parece funcionar:

> ```
> 0x7ffdffc31500 virtual void D::update()
> ```

---

- ¿Por qué al añadir un destructor virtual falla en tiempo de ejecución en GCC pero no falla en tiempo de ejecución en CLang?
- ¿Qué compilador se está comportando de manera correcta?
- ¿El código incurre en comportamiento indefinido?
- El constructor de movimiento de `std::reference_wrapper` está borrado, pero construyo un `B` con un temporal ¿cómo es posible?.

Comment: ¿Puede ser ésto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c, aunque no explican las razones del diferente comportamiento de los compiladores.

Comment: No. En esa pregunta hablan de un destructor puramente virtual, yo estoy usando un destructor por defecto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> El constructor de movimiento de std::reference_wrapper está borrado, pero construyo un B con un temporal ¿cómo es posible?.

Vamos a simplificar un poco el código:

```
int main()
{
  std::reference_wrapper<B> ref{D{}};
  return 0;
}
```

El código no va a compilar ni en GCC ni en CLANG y el motivo es muy sencillo... `reference_wrapper` no dispone de un constructor que admita un `r-value` y es algo que tiene todo el sentido del mundo ya que después de llamar a `D{}` el objeto se destruye y el `reference_wrapper` apuntará a un elmento que ya no es válido... es una protección obvia.

Huelga decir que el código anterior fallará tanto si se ha declarado el destructor o no.

Pues bien, en tu ejemplo lo que sucede es que el `reference_wrapper` se encapsula dentro de una pila `std::stack`. Y es aquí donde empezamos a movernos en terreno pantanoso. Si bien no podemos crear un `reference_wrapper` a partir de un *r_value*, sí que podemos sortear esta protección haciéndole creer al `reference_wrapper` que el objeto es un *l-value*:

```
void func(B && b)
{
  std::reference_wrapper<B> ref(b); // *
}

int main()
{
  std::reference_wrapper<B>(D{}); // ERROR
  func(D{});                      // OK!!!
}
```

¿Qué está pasando? Facil. `func` recibe un *r-value* pero lo trata internamente como un *l-value*, luego en la línea `*` se está invocando al constructor:

```
std::reference_wrapper<B>(B&)
```

Y este constructor sí que es un constructor válido. Bueno, deja de serlo en el momento en el que el objeto al que referencia se destruye, pero esa es otra historia.

Podemos verificar este punto usando `std::move`:

```
void func(B && b)
{
  std::reference_wrapper<B> ref(std::move(b)); // ERROR
}
```

El caso es que en tu ejemplo estás *engañando* al `reference_wrapper` y por eso no te saltan errores en tiempo de compilación:

```
void push(B &&b)
{
    bases.push(b); // <<--- b es un l-value
}
```

> ¿Por qué al añadir un destructor virtual falla en tiempo de ejecución en GCC pero no falla en tiempo de ejecución en CLang?

Bueno, ya hemos visto que el código de la pregunta es inseguro por definición. En este caso el comportamiento esperado es indeterminado y depende única y exclusivamente de la forma en que cada compilador gestiona la tabla de funciones virtuales.

> ¿Qué compilador se está comportando de manera correcta?

Ambos lo están haciendo bien. La única diferencia entre ambos es que gestionan de forma diferente la tabla de funciones virtuales y eso propicia que GCC se de cuenta de que estás intentando invocar un destructor que ya no existe (la tabla de funciones virtuales se ha limpiado).

> ¿El código incurre en comportamiento indefinido?

Obviamente sí. El comportamiento final dependerá de cómo gestione el compilador la tabla de funciones virtuales.

## Aclaración

Pero... ¿por qué cambia el comportamiento al declarar el destructor?

El motivo no es tanto declarar el destructor sino que el destructor se está declarando de forma virtual. Aquí estamos usando polimorfismo, luego si los destructores no son virtuales podemos tener problemas al liberar memoria dinámica y recursos.

Al declarar el destructor virtual estamos forzando a que se invoquen todos los destructores de la herencia... mientras que sin dicho destructor únicamente se invocará el destructor de `B`. Esto, como se ve, tiene impacto en el caso de GCC ya que el comportamiento final cambia.

He intentado preparar una respuesta sobre esto mostrando cambios en el ensamblado resultante pero la respuesta se complicaba demasiado... así que no he añadido esa información en beneficio de una respuesta más limpia y legible